# Navigation bar link not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

The navigation bar on this [Site](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen.html) is not working properly.
Clicking on "Leistungsspektrum" in the navigation bar says that The requested URL /leistunsspektrum.html was not found on this server.
The site is named "leistungsspektrum.html" on the server.

HTML: [link](http://pastebin.com/7EC58Xeu)

CSS: [link](http://pastebin.com/8karqH6Q)

Whats wrong?

Comment: You should post your code here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed a `g` out in your link.

Instead of

```
<a href="http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/leistunsspektrum.html" title="" class="mn2 active"></a>
```

It should be

```
<a href="http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/leistungsspektrum.html" title="" class="mn2 active"></a>
```

As a sidenote: **please** include your code in your question! Links to external websites are useless to Stack Overflow if those websites disappear from the internet one day. Not only that but many people will take one look at a HTML/CSS-related question with no code and click straight back off it.

**Include your code!**

Answer (score 2):

Simple spelling mistake

use

```
leistungsspektrum.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typed the url wrong. It should be "leistungsspektrum.html". Not "leistunsspektrum.html".

Hope it helps.

Kind regards,
Bart Roelofs

Answer (score 1):

Update your URL to this, it just a small typo error:

http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/leistungsspektrum.html

Comment: @DanielHernandez: I have not down vote your question. It could be by any eligible User from the community who feels it deserve for down vote. Same is applicable for Up Vote also. You can follow the Stackoverflow FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more details.